# How to set reminder for facebook friends birthday in phonegap(android)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

The last task of my phonegap(android) project is to set the reminder for the birthdays of facebook friends list. i'm able to fetch facebook friends birthday list but stuck up with setting the reminder for upcoming birthday. searched alot in google but could not get any relevant solutions, please help me if anybody had done with this

Answer (score 0):

For PhoneGap Android, you can use Notification API.

[Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my issue is in phonegap @Sahil Mittal